# How to get the HTML output from a rendered component

Tags: html, reactjs, prism.js

I am a newbie to the ReactJS world and trying to get into it. I am working on a style guide for which I need to display some HTML code as an example. I am using ReactPrism for that and I am not able to get the HTML output inside my PrismCode component, I have find a work around by using react-to-jsx which shows the JSX code instead of HTML.
This is the code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {PrismCode} from "react-prism";
import reactToJsx from 'react-to-jsx';

class CodePreview extends React.Component {
    render (){
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.children}
                <h5>Code example</h5>
                <pre>
                    <PrismCode className="language-javascript">
                        {reactToJsx(this.props.children)}
                    </PrismCode>
                </pre>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default CodePreview;
```

So basically I want to render this.props.children (the component) as HTML code and not the content of it in the PrismCode
I even tried the following as shown on https://github.com/tomchentw/react-prism, but it doesn't work. Not sure what I am doing wrong!

```
<PrismCode className="language-javascript">
    {require("raw-loader!./PrismCode")}
</PrismCode>
```

Comment: <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__HTML: myHTML}}></div> <- If you want to paste in RAW Html into some component

Comment: thanks for the response, I had tried this but it didn't work as this.props.children passes an object from which I need the HTML output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered writing your docs in markdown? I added some special tags for react:

````
```react:mirror
<Slider
  value={7}
/>
```
````

This will show the rendered component and also the JSX syntax highlighted.

````
```react:demo
<PropsEditor>
  <Slider
    value={7}
  />
</PropsEditor>
```
````

This will render the component as well as a live editor to manipulate any props on the component.

````
```react
  <SomeComponent />
```
````

Will just syntax highlight but not render the component.

At the top of my markdown file I can import any components I am using in the doc:

```
---
imports:
  - import Slider from '../src/slider'
  - import PropsEditor from 'props-editor'
---
```

The advantage of this way is that your docs work as normal markdown and it's easy to get the JSX as you have it as a string.

**To get the HTML source** I have a "View Source `</>` button which prints formatted html dynamically when clicked:

[image]

The steps are:

- on click get the html of the react component
- format the html using prism and a beautifier
- insert it into the DOM

So wrap your react component and make a reference to the node:

```
<div ref={(n) => (this.fenceView = n)}>
```

And on click add the output below the component, relevant bits:

```
import prismjs from 'prismjs';
import beautify from 'xml-beautifier';

const RE_HTML_COMMENTS = /<!--[\s\S]*?-->/g;

removeCodeSource() {
  const existingHtmlCode = this.fenceView.querySelector('.fence-generated-html');
  if (existingHtmlCode) existingHtmlCode.remove();
}

renderCodeSource() {
  const html = this.fenceView.children[0].innerHTML.replace(RE_HTML_COMMENTS, '');
  const fenceCode = beautify(html, '  ');
  const highlightedCode = prismjs.highlight(fenceCode, prismjs.languages.html);
  this.removeCodeSource();
  this.fenceView.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',
    `<pre class="fence-generated-html language-html"><code>${highlightedCode}</code></pre>`);
}
```

Comment: what I am trying to do is the following: I have some react components like a button, input elements, forms etc and I want to show that component and it's HTML code on the page as well. So this.props.children renders the component, but don't know how to get the HTML from the rendered object in this case this.props.children.

Comment: it's quite easy to do with a ref to the component and then use vanilla javascript to get the html and format it with prism, I'll post an example I do the same thing